# Usage of phone number & confusion regrad iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, ios7

All,I am making app for reminders & its kind of social reminders. I can share my reminders with my contacts. I want to make it like whatsapp. Can we use user's mobile number for this purpose? Or will apple reject it? Please tell me more, if anyone has done such app before?
Thanx.

Comment: You don't provide enough information, use the mobile number how, how do you want to obtain the mobile number etc.? (You can't programatically obtain the number on iOS). And why has this question got an android tag, what's it to do with android?

Comment: Hi, Mr H. I Just want user's phone number. I am supposed to use textfeild to get it from user. Is that fine with iOS or will they reject app due to privacy?

Comment: Do you mean you are going to prompt the user and ask the user to enter  their phone number? There's nothing wrong with that. Or something else?

Comment: Yes asking them & storing their numbers on server. is that fine?

Comment: IMO there is nothing wrong with that - you are asking the user to provide their phone number, if they don't want to give it to you then they have the option not to. This isn't the right forum for this question, Stack Exchange has a specific forum just for this type of question but I forget what its url is. There is a specific forum for asking about app store issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask user for any information, no matter how personal.  In terms of Apple guidelines, here's a few things to bear in mind:

1. asking is fine, but taking (via a hack or whatever) will get you bounced.
2. the ask has to be essential to the service the app delivers. in other words, it's perfectly okay for a retirement calculator to ask about how much money user has in the bank, but not so okay for a tic-tac-toe app.
3. editorially, be very clear and honest about how you'll use the information (Apple might not catch you here, but you should do this anyway to motivate the user's answer).
4. the app must remain functional even if the user opts not to provide the information.  for example, the retirement calculator should supply a default bank balance and carry on.